# Docker container won't stay running after end of ssh session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, docker

So I am using an Ubuntu linux machine in Oracle Cloud. I have the network setup, the proper ports open. Whenever I am SSH'd into the machine and I explicitly run the container with podman I can access homeassistant  from the url just fine.

However, when I log out/end the SSH session on the server running the container, it continues running for about a second and then I can no longer make successful HTTP requests to the container (ie it's down).

It seems very peculiar. I am using the -d argument to start the container in detached mode.

```
docker run -d   --name homeassistant   --privileged   --restart=unless-stopped   -e TZ=America/New_York   -v ~/homeconfig:/config   --network=host   ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable
```

When I log back in, I see the container status as not `Up` but, `Created`

```
ubuntu@homeassist:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                         COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
48eb2f443ac7  ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable              5 minutes ago  Created                 homeassistant
```

I've tried a few different argument permutations (ie adding -t, running with nohup &) but still it's the same behavior. I also tried on Oracle Linux as well. I wonder if it's an artifact of the actual free tier on Oracle Cloud?

This is the log I get from running `docker logs homeassistant`

```
2023-03-14 10:32:22.851 ERROR (MainThread) [async_upnp_client.ssdp] Received error: [Errno 101] Network unreachable, transport: <_SelectorDatagramTransport fd=26 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>, socket: <asyncio.TransportSocket fd=26, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 54635)>
2023-03-14 10:32:22.898 ERROR (MainThread) [async_upnp_client.ssdp] Received error: [Errno 101] Network unreachable, transport: <_SelectorDatagramTransport fd=30 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>, socket: <asyncio.TransportSocket fd=30, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('::', 58622, 0, 0)>
2023-03-14 10:32:22.901 WARNING (MainThread) [zeroconf] Error with socket 17 (('10.0.2.100', 5353))): [Errno 101] Network unreachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1062, in sendto
    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network unreachable
2023-03-14 10:32:22.902 WARNING (MainThread) [zeroconf] Error with socket 18 (('fe80::3488:51ff:fe32:fd5a', 5353, 0, 2))): [Errno 101] Network unreachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1062, in sendto
    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network unreachable
```

---

For right now I have resolved this by replacing `podman` with `docker.io`. However - it's not clear to me why podman would behave differently.

Comment: Are you sure your VPS/VM stays running after you log out? Check `uptime` and its logs. Maybe there’s also some cloud platform logs that could be interesting.

Comment: yes - uptime is solid. I'm adding to the original post an error I get when looking at the container logs

Comment: Maybe you need to create a systemd service? Something like `podman generate systemd --new --name ... > ~/.config/systemd/user/my.service`, `systemctl --user daemon-reload` , `loginctl enable-linger`, `systemctl --user start my.service`

Comment: See the tip "_A rootless container running in detached mode is closed at logout_" in [troubleshooting.md](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#21-a-rootless-container-running-in-detached-mode-is-closed-at-logout)